# Why is "offside" a tag synonym for "officiating"?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms

I was browsing the tags on Sports SE and arrived at the tag [synonyms](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/officiating/synonyms) for [officiating](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/officiating).

There you can see [offside](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offside) listed as a synonym alongside [officiating](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/officiating), [referee](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/referee), and [umpire](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umpire).

Offside is a foul or a condition in many sports, but is not synonymous with officiating, referee or umpire. [offside](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offside) should be removed from those synonyms.

Comment: Hmm. I think that was one of Ed's. Anyone else have ideas?

Comment: If I am reading the [list of synonyms](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) correctly, the synonym was created in January 2013. I found discussion around that time neither in chat nor on meta - maybe somebody has better luck searching than me.

Comment: Of course, it is clear that *tag synonym* is not the same thing as usual meaning of the word *synonym*. (So the tags that are chosen as synonyms do not necessarily have to be synonymous in the usual sense of the word.)

Comment: I agree with Nij, I don't think it needs a separate tag.

Answer (score 2):

Determining whether a particular situation, regardless of sport, involves

- an offside position
- an offside offence
- any appropriate penalty, and
- how to indicate the offside

are all aspects of officiating.

This synonym is perfectly appropriate and should remain.